# Running unix ksh command in csh

Tags: linux, unix, ksh, csh

I'm trying to run below one line command in csh but it doesn't work

```
find . -type d -name "mydir" -exec touch {}/abc.txt \;
```

This command runs fine in ksh. 
I'm just trying to create empty file(abc.txt) within all directories named `mydir`. Could anyone help me with the csh command to do this?

Comment: This should work fine in csh. What's "not working"? What does the `find` command output without the `-exec`?

Answer (score 3):

`{` and `}` are meta-characters in both ksh and csh, but they're treated differently.

For example, this:

```
{foo,bar}/abc.txt
```

expands to

```
foo/abc.txt bar/abc.txt
```

in both shells, but in ksh if there are no commas between the braces, they're not treated specially, whereas in csh they're treated specially whether there are any commas or not. As a result, in ksh

```
{}/abc.txt
```

is simply `{}/abc.txt`, but in csh it's replaced by just `/abc.txt`.

The fix is to quote the braces:

```
find . -type d -name "mydir" -exec touch '{}/abc.txt' \;
```

Comment: Thanks Keith for nice explanation. Adding a quote around braces fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the following:

```
find . -type d -name "mydir" -print |  sed 's/$/\/abc.txt/g' | xargs touch
```